# How to solve cache? issue when using jasmine standalone

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

When I go to `SpecRunner.html` in my browser, the unit tests run fine. The issue I am having is if I change one of the tests, or the code that it tests and refresh the page, it doesn't load the new tests or change at all. I thought that this would be a cache issue, but I have the chrome dev tools `disable cache` selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: tried restarting my computer, nothing. Clearing cache, nothing. I don't understand why this would be happening.

EDIT2: tried force reload, nothing... changed the file name and reference and still loaded the old code...

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your specific problem, as there are a million reasons this could happen.

For me, it was because I had deleted some files and then re-added them as a git submodule. After doing this, `ls` was showing me the OLD files, and I didn't realize that I had to go up a directory and then back in to interact with the new files I had just pulled down.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I ended up here when looking for an answer, so here's my solution in case it helps anyone - I was having a similar problem with jasmine-rails, removing jasmine-specs.js from public/assets did it for me. I'm using the jasmine-rails gem from https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails.